# Mysql query optimization with dates

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to optimize the following query:

```
    SELECT a2 AS 'b_actual_pair', 
       a1 AS 'c_actual_date', 
       a3 AS 'd_actual_value', 
       b1 AS 'e_1m_date', 
       b3 AS 'f_1m_value',
       c1 AS 'g_2m_date',
       c3 AS 'h_2m_value',
       d1 AS 'i_3m_date',
       d3 AS 'j_3m_value',
       e1 AS 'k_4m_date',
       e3 AS 'l_4m_value',
       f1 AS 'm_5m_date',
       f3 AS 'n_5m_value'
FROM   (SELECT crd.b_date  AS 'a1', 
               crd.c_pair  AS 'a2',
               crd.d_value AS 'a3' 
        FROM   item_raw_data crd 
        WHERE  crd.a_unique_id > ( (SELECT crd.a_unique_id 
                                    FROM   item_raw_data crd 
                                    ORDER  BY crd.a_unique_id DESC 
                                    LIMIT  0, 1) - ((SELECT 
                                   Count(DISTINCT c_pair) 
                                                     FROM   item_raw_data)) ) 
        ORDER  BY crd.b_date DESC) a, 
       (SELECT crd.b_date  AS 'b1', 
               crd.c_pair  AS 'b2',
               crd.d_value AS 'b3' 
        FROM   item_raw_data crd 
        WHERE  crd.b_date < ( (SELECT crd.b_date 
                               FROM   item_raw_data crd 
                               ORDER  BY crd.b_date DESC 
                               LIMIT  0, 1) - INTERVAL 1 minute ) 
               AND crd.a_unique_id > ( (SELECT Max(x.a_unique_id) 
                                        FROM   (SELECT crd.a_unique_id, 
                                                       crd.b_date, 
                                                       crd.c_pair, 
                                                       crd.d_value 
                                                FROM   item_raw_data crd 
                                                WHERE  crd.b_date < ( 
                                                       (SELECT crd.b_date 
                                                        FROM   item_raw_data 
                                                               crd 
                                                        ORDER  BY crd.b_date 
                                                                  DESC 
                                                        LIMIT  0, 1) - 
                                                       INTERVAL 1 minute ) 
                                                ORDER  BY crd.b_date DESC) x) - 
                                           ((SELECT Count(DISTINCT c_pair) 
                                             FROM   item_raw_data)) ) 
        ORDER  BY crd.b_date DESC) b,
       (SELECT crd.b_date  AS 'c1', 
               crd.c_pair  AS 'c2', 
               crd.d_value AS 'c3' 
        FROM   item_raw_data crd 
        WHERE  crd.b_date < ( (SELECT crd.b_date 
                               FROM   item_raw_data crd 
                               ORDER  BY crd.b_date DESC 
                               LIMIT  0, 1) - INTERVAL 2 minute ) 
               AND crd.a_unique_id > ( (SELECT Max(x.a_unique_id) 
                                        FROM   (SELECT crd.a_unique_id, 
                                                       crd.b_date, 
                                                       crd.c_pair, 
                                                       crd.d_value 
                                                FROM   item_raw_data crd 
                                                WHERE  crd.b_date < ( 
                                                       (SELECT crd.b_date 
                                                        FROM   item_raw_data 
                                                               crd 
                                                        ORDER  BY crd.b_date 
                                                                  DESC 
                                                        LIMIT  0, 1) - 
                                                       INTERVAL 2 minute ) 
                                                ORDER  BY crd.b_date DESC) x) - 
                                           ((SELECT Count(DISTINCT c_pair) 
                                             FROM   item_raw_data)) ) 
        ORDER  BY crd.b_date DESC) c,
       (SELECT crd.b_date  AS 'd1', 
               crd.c_pair  AS 'd2', 
               crd.d_value AS 'd3' 
        FROM   item_raw_data crd 
        WHERE  crd.b_date < ( (SELECT crd.b_date 
                               FROM   item_raw_data crd 
                               ORDER  BY crd.b_date DESC 
                               LIMIT  0, 1) - INTERVAL 3 minute ) 
               AND crd.a_unique_id > ( (SELECT Max(x.a_unique_id) 
                                        FROM   (SELECT crd.a_unique_id, 
                                                       crd.b_date, 
                                                       crd.c_pair, 
                                                       crd.d_value 
                                                FROM   item_raw_data crd 
                                                WHERE  crd.b_date < ( 
                                                       (SELECT crd.b_date 
                                                        FROM   item_raw_data 
                                                               crd 
                                                        ORDER  BY crd.b_date 
                                                                  DESC 
                                                        LIMIT  0, 1) - 
                                                       INTERVAL 3 minute ) 
                                                ORDER  BY crd.b_date DESC) x) - 
                                           ((SELECT Count(DISTINCT c_pair) 
                                             FROM   item_raw_data)) ) 
        ORDER  BY crd.b_date DESC) d,
       (SELECT crd.b_date  AS 'e1', 
               crd.c_pair  AS 'e2', 
               crd.d_value AS 'e3' 
        FROM   item_raw_data crd 
        WHERE  crd.b_date < ( (SELECT crd.b_date 
                               FROM   item_raw_data crd 
                               ORDER  BY crd.b_date DESC 
                               LIMIT  0, 1) - INTERVAL 4 minute ) 
               AND crd.a_unique_id > ( (SELECT Max(x.a_unique_id) 
                                        FROM   (SELECT crd.a_unique_id, 
                                                       crd.b_date, 
                                                       crd.c_pair, 
                                                       crd.d_value 
                                                FROM   item_raw_data crd 
                                                WHERE  crd.b_date < ( 
                                                       (SELECT crd.b_date 
                                                        FROM   item_raw_data 
                                                               crd 
                                                        ORDER  BY crd.b_date 
                                                                  DESC 
                                                        LIMIT  0, 1) - 
                                                       INTERVAL 4 minute ) 
                                                ORDER  BY crd.b_date DESC) x) - 
                                           ((SELECT Count(DISTINCT c_pair) 
                                             FROM   item_raw_data)) ) 
        ORDER  BY crd.b_date DESC) e,
       (SELECT crd.b_date  AS 'f1', 
               crd.c_pair  AS 'f2', 
               crd.d_value AS 'f3' 
        FROM   item_raw_data crd 
        WHERE  crd.b_date < ( (SELECT crd.b_date 
                               FROM   item_raw_data crd 
                               ORDER  BY crd.b_date DESC 
                               LIMIT  0, 1) - INTERVAL 5 minute ) 
               AND crd.a_unique_id > ( (SELECT Max(x.a_unique_id) 
                                        FROM   (SELECT crd.a_unique_id, 
                                                       crd.b_date, 
                                                       crd.c_pair, 
                                                       crd.d_value 
                                                FROM   item_raw_data crd 
                                                WHERE  crd.b_date < ( 
                                                       (SELECT crd.b_date 
                                                        FROM   item_raw_data 
                                                               crd 
                                                        ORDER  BY crd.b_date 
                                                                  DESC 
                                                        LIMIT  0, 1) - 
                                                       INTERVAL 5 minute ) 
                                                ORDER  BY crd.b_date DESC) x) - 
                                           ((SELECT Count(DISTINCT c_pair) 
                                             FROM   item_raw_data)) ) 
        ORDER  BY crd.b_date DESC) f        
WHERE  
    a.a2 = b.b2 
        and 
    b.b2 = c.c2
        and 
    c.c2 = d.d2
        and 
    d.d2 = e.e2
        and
    e.e2 = f.f2
```

The output of this query is the following:

[image]

**1. The data behind** `items_raw_data` is the following:

-every 5 seconds 110 items are inserted in the database with their current prices

-`actual_pair` or `c_pair` is a reference to a main table which contains the full item description, not of much relevance

-luckily the 110 rows are inserted in 2 seconds, leaving a gap of 3 seconds. This makes it easier to build the queries.

**2. The aim of this query** is to use this data to do a chart with live prices but we need to further expand the query to (example) `10 minutes, 15 minutes, 1 hour, 2 hours` etc... So you will be able to see an items price with its value now and few moments back in time.

**3. The problem** is that this query takes 2.5 seconds to run with 450.000 (few hours data present and we need up to 1 week of data) total data rows and 6 set of data (actual, 1m, 2m, 3m, 4m, 5m).

**What have we tried so far:**

1. Using tables as Memory instead of INNO reduced the query times from 2.5 seconds to 2 seconds. The system has 64gb ECC RAM and a 12 core CPU and an NVMe drive, hardware shouldn't be a problem.
2. Finding all this data for each item individually yields worse results than all the items together.
3. Doing exactly the same in server-side language (Java) through threaded code is slower also.
4. Tried using Inner Join's instead of Where, similar result.

**An easier to view query:**

```
SELECT crd.b_date  AS 'a1', 
       crd.c_pair  AS 'a2', 
       crd.d_value AS 'a3' 
FROM   items_raw_data crd 
WHERE  crd.a_unique_id > ( (SELECT crd.a_unique_id 
                            FROM   items_raw_data crd 
                            ORDER  BY crd.a_unique_id DESC 
                            LIMIT  0, 1) - ((SELECT Count(DISTINCT c_pair) 
                                             FROM   items_raw_data)) ) 
ORDER  BY crd.b_date DESC
```

And the results:

[image]

This is for the actual prices only.

Table description:

[image]

**Update 1**

Added explain:

[image]

**Update 2**

Here are the links to download the database, with the query also (own hosting server):

Item raw data SQL: https://cloud.technorah.com/index.php/s/sR3mdK2Oos2EbC3

SQL Query: https://cloud.technorah.com/index.php/s/bdndmLGAUfpduif

**Update 3**

1. Using @hunteke query gave a result of 4.7 seconds, which was very strange because the query and the advices seem logical.
2. Using @hunteke's tips we changed the following:

   ```
   SELECT a_unique_id FROM item_raw_data ORDER BY a_unique_id DESC LIMIT  0, 1
   ```

   to

   ```
   SELECT MAX(a_unique_id) FROM item_raw_data
   ```

this lowered the query time from 2.8 seconds to 2.7 seconds. Adding `USE INDEX(primary)` on main queries further improved the time from 2.7 seconds to 2.6 seconds.

**Update 4**

We failed at a basic task, using `Timestamp` instead of `int(11) - primary key` in the `order by`. The latest inserted date is also the latest unique id inserted. So changing from `ORDER  BY crd.b_date` to `ORDER  BY crd.a_unique_id` lowered the query by more than 1 SECOND, from 2.6 to 1.3, almost half.

**So the actual query looks like this, completly reworked.** The execution time changed from 1.3 seconds to 0.55s

```
SELECT * 
FROM   
        (SELECT sub.a_unique_id AS 'a0', 
            sub.b_date          AS 'a1', 
            sub.c_pair          AS 'a2', 
            sub.d_value         AS 'a3' 
        FROM   (SELECT * 
                FROM   item_raw_data) sub, 
            (SELECT crd.a_unique_id AS 'max_id', 
                    crd.b_date      AS 'xdate' 
                FROM   item_raw_data crd
                ORDER  BY crd.a_unique_id DESC 
                LIMIT  0, 1) aux 
        WHERE  sub.b_date <= aux.xdate 
            AND sub.a_unique_id > ( aux.max_id - (SELECT 
                                        Count(DISTINCT c_pair) AS 
                                        max_rows 
                                                        FROM   item_raw_data) 
                                        ) 
        ORDER  BY sub.a_unique_id DESC) a,


        (SELECT sub.a_unique_id AS 'b0', 
            sub.b_date          AS 'b1', 
            sub.c_pair          AS 'b2', 
            sub.d_value         AS 'b3' 
        FROM   (SELECT * 
                FROM   item_raw_data) sub, 
            (SELECT crd.a_unique_id AS 'max_id', 
                    crd.b_date      AS 'xdate' 
                FROM   item_raw_data crd
                WHERE  crd.b_date < (SELECT ( crdx.b_date - INTERVAL 1 minute ) 
                                    FROM   item_raw_data crdx 
                                    ORDER  BY crdx.a_unique_id DESC 
                                    LIMIT  0, 1) 
                ORDER  BY crd.a_unique_id DESC 
                LIMIT  0, 1) aux 
        WHERE  sub.b_date <= aux.xdate 
            AND sub.a_unique_id > ( aux.max_id - (SELECT 
                                        Count(DISTINCT c_pair) AS 
                                        max_rows 
                                                        FROM   item_raw_data) 
                                        ) 
        ORDER  BY sub.a_unique_id DESC) b, 


    (SELECT sub.a_unique_id AS 'c0', 
            sub.b_date      AS 'c1', 
            sub.c_pair      AS 'c2', 
            sub.d_value     AS 'c3' 
        FROM   (SELECT *
                FROM   item_raw_data) sub, 
            (SELECT crd.a_unique_id AS 'max_id', 
                    crd.b_date      AS 'xdate' 
                FROM   item_raw_data crd
                WHERE  crd.b_date < (SELECT ( crdx.b_date - INTERVAL 2 minute ) 
                                    FROM   item_raw_data crdx 
                                    ORDER  BY crdx.a_unique_id DESC 
                                    LIMIT  0, 1) 
                ORDER  BY crd.a_unique_id DESC 
                LIMIT  0, 1) aux 
        WHERE  sub.b_date <= aux.xdate 
            AND sub.a_unique_id > ( aux.max_id - (SELECT 
                                        Count(DISTINCT c_pair) AS 
                                        max_rows 
                                                        FROM   item_raw_data) 
                                        ) 
        ORDER  BY sub.a_unique_id DESC) c,


    (SELECT sub.a_unique_id AS 'd0', 
            sub.b_date      AS 'd1', 
            sub.c_pair      AS 'd2', 
            sub.d_value     AS 'd3' 
        FROM   (SELECT *
                FROM   item_raw_data) sub, 
            (SELECT crd.a_unique_id AS 'max_id', 
                    crd.b_date      AS 'xdate' 
                FROM   item_raw_data crd
                WHERE  crd.b_date < (SELECT ( crdx.b_date - INTERVAL 3 minute ) 
                                    FROM   item_raw_data crdx 
                                    ORDER  BY crdx.a_unique_id DESC 
                                    LIMIT  0, 1) 
                ORDER  BY crd.a_unique_id DESC 
                LIMIT  0, 1) aux 
        WHERE  sub.b_date <= aux.xdate 
            AND sub.a_unique_id > ( aux.max_id - (SELECT 
                                        Count(DISTINCT c_pair) AS 
                                        max_rows 
                                                        FROM   item_raw_data) 
                                        ) 
        ORDER  BY sub.a_unique_id DESC) d,      


    (SELECT sub.a_unique_id AS 'e0', 
            sub.b_date      AS 'e1', 
            sub.c_pair      AS 'e2', 
            sub.d_value     AS 'e3' 
        FROM   (SELECT *
                FROM   item_raw_data) sub, 
            (SELECT crd.a_unique_id AS 'max_id', 
                    crd.b_date      AS 'xdate' 
                FROM   item_raw_data crd
                WHERE  crd.b_date < (SELECT ( crdx.b_date - INTERVAL 4 minute ) 
                                    FROM   item_raw_data crdx 
                                    ORDER  BY crdx.a_unique_id DESC 
                                    LIMIT  0, 1) 
                ORDER  BY crd.a_unique_id DESC 
                LIMIT  0, 1) aux 
        WHERE  sub.b_date <= aux.xdate 
            AND sub.a_unique_id > ( aux.max_id - (SELECT 
                                        Count(DISTINCT c_pair) AS 
                                        max_rows 
                                                        FROM   item_raw_data) 
                                        ) 
        ORDER  BY sub.a_unique_id DESC) e,


    (SELECT sub.a_unique_id AS 'f0', 
            sub.b_date      AS 'f1', 
            sub.c_pair      AS 'f2', 
            sub.d_value     AS 'f3' 
        FROM   (SELECT *
                FROM   item_raw_data) sub, 
            (SELECT crd.a_unique_id AS 'max_id', 
                    crd.b_date      AS 'xdate' 
                FROM   item_raw_data crd
                WHERE  crd.b_date < (SELECT ( crdx.b_date - INTERVAL 5 minute ) 
                                    FROM   item_raw_data crdx 
                                    ORDER  BY crdx.a_unique_id DESC 
                                    LIMIT  0, 1) 
                ORDER  BY crd.a_unique_id DESC 
                LIMIT  0, 1) aux 
        WHERE  sub.b_date <= aux.xdate 
            AND sub.a_unique_id > ( aux.max_id - (SELECT 
                                        Count(DISTINCT c_pair) AS 
                                        max_rows 
                                                        FROM   item_raw_data) 
                                        ) 
        ORDER  BY sub.a_unique_id DESC) f

WHERE  
    a.a2 = b.b2
        AND
    b.b2 = c.c2 
        AND 
    c.c2 = d.d2
        AND
    d.d2 = e.e2
        AND
    e.e2 = f.f2
```

While this is good, lowering from 1.3s almost to 0.55s, we can now use this but we are still looking for further improvements, not only to yield a better result, but an more in-depth understanding of optimization on such big queries and MySQL. **Will keep updating the query execution time as table grows**.

Comment: My guess is that you might not get too much help here because the query is so massive and most folks won't be able to completely digest it.  Is there any chance you could post a more minimal version of the query?

Comment: You should desc your current table and expect result that your query. instead your massive statement.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added an minimal version

Comment: @FrankAK also added the table description, its a simple table but with lots of rows.

Comment: I don't see any obvious performance problems in your simplified query.  You do have two subqueries in the `WHERE` clause, but they both appear to be non correlated, and so should not be performance killers.

Comment: What is the [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) output for the query?

Comment: @hunteke added explain and files to download the database with the query also.

Answer (score 1):

The EXPLAIN output says that the optimizer is choosing to ignore any indexes for 4 of the PRIMARY selections.  I can't say with certainty *why* it's not, but I have a strong suspicion it's to do with the heavyish use of subqueries:  MySQL is notoriously bad at optimizing subqueries, and the general advice is "don't use them."  Not always tenable.

So the improvements that I can offer now:

1. When you need the maximum, use `MAX`.  Don't `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.  The `ORDER BY` requires O(*n* log *n*) operations to sort, while the `MAX` function's worst case requires just O(*n*) to find the maximum value (scan through the entire table).  If you have an index on that column with high-cardinality, then `MAX` will likely take even less, at O(log *n*).  You can see this slow down via all the filesort's in the EXPLAIN output.

   ```
   -- okay
   SELECT a_unique_id FROM item_raw_data ORDER BY a_unique_id DESC LIMIT  0, 1

   -- better
   SELECT MAX(a_unique_id) FROM item_raw_data
   ```
2. There should be no need to select columns that aren't utilized in subqueries.  I would assume the query optimizer would get rid of them, but I have assumed wrong with MySQL before.  *Especially* when it comes to subqueries.  So, with a grain of salt:

   ```
   -- okay
   SELECT MAX(a_unique_id)
   FROM (SELECT a_unique_id, b_date, c_pair, d_value FROM ...)

   -- better
   SELECT MAX(a_unique_id)
   FROM (SELECT a_unique_id FROM ...)
   ```
3. The MySQL optimizer is ignoring indexes.  You might give MySQL a strong hint to use the proper indexes with `USE INDEX(<indexname>)`.  Doing so results in a far simpler query plan that also makes better use of indexes:

   ```
   +----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
   | id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys           | key                     | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra                                              |
   +----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
   |  1 | PRIMARY     | bb    | NULL       | range | PRIMARY                 | PRIMARY                 | 4       | NULL |   1540 |    33.33 | Using where                                        |
   |  1 | PRIMARY     | aa    | NULL       | range | PRIMARY                 | PRIMARY                 | 4       | NULL |    110 |     0.90 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
   |  1 | PRIMARY     | cc    | NULL       | range | PRIMARY                 | PRIMARY                 | 4       | NULL |   2860 |     0.30 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
   |  1 | PRIMARY     | dd    | NULL       | range | PRIMARY                 | PRIMARY                 | 4       | NULL |   7568 |     0.30 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
   |  1 | PRIMARY     | ee    | NULL       | range | PRIMARY                 | PRIMARY                 | 4       | NULL |  10188 |     0.30 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
   |  1 | PRIMARY     | ff    | NULL       | range | PRIMARY                 | PRIMARY                 | 4       | NULL |  12972 |     0.30 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
   | 21 | SUBQUERY    | ll    | NULL       | ALL   | RAW_DATA_PAIR_UNIQUE_ID | NULL                    | NULL    | NULL | 499198 |    50.00 | Using where                                        |
   | 17 | SUBQUERY    | kk    | NULL       | ALL   | RAW_DATA_PAIR_UNIQUE_ID | NULL                    | NULL    | NULL | 499198 |    50.00 | Using where                                        |
   | 13 | SUBQUERY    | jj    | NULL       | ALL   | RAW_DATA_PAIR_UNIQUE_ID | NULL                    | NULL    | NULL | 499198 |    50.00 | Using where                                        |
   |  9 | SUBQUERY    | ii    | NULL       | ALL   | RAW_DATA_PAIR_UNIQUE_ID | NULL                    | NULL    | NULL | 499198 |    50.00 | Using where                                        |
   |  5 | SUBQUERY    | hh    | NULL       | ALL   | RAW_DATA_PAIR_UNIQUE_ID | NULL                    | NULL    | NULL | 499198 |    50.00 | Using where                                        |
   |  3 | SUBQUERY    | gg    | NULL       | index | RAW_DATA_PAIR_UNIQUE_ID | RAW_DATA_PAIR_UNIQUE_ID | 4       | NULL | 499198 |   100.00 | Using index                                        |
   +----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
   ```
4. And finally, I've reorganizing the query so it's much more obvious (if you scroll right) how the sections differ (the `INTERVAL`s) and where the `USE INDEX`'s are.  The `aa`, `bb`, `cc` (etc.) tables names are there merely to identify where each part maps to the query plan (above):

   ```
   SELECT
     a2 AS 'b_actual_pair', a1 AS 'c_actual_date', a3 AS 'd_actual_value',
     b1 AS 'e_1m_date', b3 AS 'f_1m_value',
     c1 AS 'g_2m_date', c3 AS 'h_2m_value',
     d1 AS 'i_3m_date', d3 AS 'j_3m_value',
     e1 AS 'k_4m_date', e3 AS 'l_4m_value',
     f1 AS 'm_5m_date', f3 AS 'n_5m_value'
   FROM
     (SELECT b_date AS a1, c_pair AS a2, d_value AS a3 FROM item_raw_data aa USE INDEX(PRIMARY) WHERE a_unique_id > (SELECT MAX(a_unique_id) - COUNT(DISTINCT c_pair) FROM item_raw_data gg USE INDEX(RAW_DATA_PAIR_UNIQUE_ID)) ORDER BY b_date DESC) AS a,
     (SELECT b_date AS b1, c_pair AS b2, d_value AS b3 FROM item_raw_data bb USE INDEX(PRIMARY) WHERE a_unique_id > (SELECT MAX(a_unique_id) - COUNT(DISTINCT c_pair) FROM item_raw_data hh WHERE b_date < (SELECT MAX(b_date) FROM item_raw_data mm) - INTERVAL 1 minute) AND b_date < (SELECT MAX(b_date) FROM item_raw_data mm) - INTERVAL 1 minute ORDER BY b_date DESC) AS b,
     (SELECT b_date AS c1, c_pair AS c2, d_value AS c3 FROM item_raw_data cc USE INDEX(PRIMARY) WHERE a_unique_id > (SELECT MAX(a_unique_id) - COUNT(DISTINCT c_pair) FROM item_raw_data ii WHERE b_date < (SELECT MAX(b_date) FROM item_raw_data mm) - INTERVAL 2 minute) AND b_date < (SELECT MAX(b_date) FROM item_raw_data mm) - INTERVAL 2 minute ORDER BY b_date DESC) AS c,
     (SELECT b_date AS d1, c_pair AS d2, d_value AS d3 FROM item_raw_data dd USE INDEX(PRIMARY) WHERE a_unique_id > (SELECT MAX(a_unique_id) - COUNT(DISTINCT c_pair) FROM item_raw_data jj WHERE b_date < (SELECT MAX(b_date) FROM item_raw_data mm) - INTERVAL 3 minute) AND b_date < (SELECT MAX(b_date) FROM item_raw_data mm) - INTERVAL 3 minute ORDER BY b_date DESC) AS d,
     (SELECT b_date AS e1, c_pair AS e2, d_value AS e3 FROM item_raw_data ee USE INDEX(PRIMARY) WHERE a_unique_id > (SELECT MAX(a_unique_id) - COUNT(DISTINCT c_pair) FROM item_raw_data kk WHERE b_date < (SELECT MAX(b_date) FROM item_raw_data mm) - INTERVAL 4 minute) AND b_date < (SELECT MAX(b_date) FROM item_raw_data mm) - INTERVAL 4 minute ORDER BY b_date DESC) AS e,
     (SELECT b_date AS f1, c_pair AS f2, d_value AS f3 FROM item_raw_data ff USE INDEX(PRIMARY) WHERE a_unique_id > (SELECT MAX(a_unique_id) - COUNT(DISTINCT c_pair) FROM item_raw_data ll WHERE b_date < (SELECT MAX(b_date) FROM item_raw_data mm) - INTERVAL 5 minute) AND b_date < (SELECT MAX(b_date) FROM item_raw_data mm) - INTERVAL 5 minute ORDER BY b_date DESC) AS f
   WHERE
       a.a2 = b.b2
   AND a.a2 = c.c2
   AND a.a2 = d.d2
   AND a.a2 = e.e2
   AND a.a2 = f.f2
   ```

And sure enough, the better use of indexes improves the speed.  It's not instant, but it takes 50% of the time of the original query on my laptop.  Meanwhile, note that if you're trying to meet a 5 second budget for data going back a week, you may still be hosed.  A warning that you may need to rethink your approach.

Comment: upvoted your comment for the tips and added my improved query, if there are no new answers or improvements for this I will mark it as the answer. Thanks for the tips, it really improved the query so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely simplify the `where` clause by doing:

```
WHERE crd.a_unique_id > (SELECT MAX(crd.a_unique_id) - COUNT(DISTINCT c_pair)
                         FROM items_raw_data crd
                        )
```

This might help a bit with performance.  You can also move the subquery to the `FROM` clause to ensure that it is executed only once.